# API connection suddenly does not work anymore via app

Tags: java, android, okhttp, api-key

I'm making a live soccer app, using [API-Sports](https://api-sports.io/)
Their [documentation](https://www.api-football.com/documentation-v3#section/Sample-Scripts/Java)
It used to work like 2 weeks ago. I also reversed my git back to when I know for sure it worked
I'm using Android Studio to build the app, and use `OkHttp` to make a request to the API.

```
public class Testing extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static String TAG = FixtureOverview.class.getName();
    String host = "v3.football.api-sports.io";
    String API_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_testing);

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate called");
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        
        Date dateTime = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String currentDate = formatter.format(dateTime);
        
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://v3.football.api-sports.io/fixtures?league=39&season=2021&date=" + currentDate)
                .get()
                .addHeader("x-rapidapi-host", host)
                .addHeader("x-rapidapi-key", API_KEY)
                .build();

        System.out.println("request: " + request);

        //Send API request
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NotNull Call call, @NotNull Response response) throws IOException {
                Log.d(TAG, " onResponse of request called");
                try (ResponseBody responseBody = response.body()) {
                    if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.d("ChampionsTeamSelect onResponse", "unexpected code");
                        throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
                    }

                    Headers responseHeaders = response.headers();
                    Log.d("ChampionsTeamSelect onResponse", "headers");
                    for (int i = 0, size = responseHeaders.size(); i < size; i++) {

                        System.out.println("response header: " + responseHeaders.name(i) + ": " + responseHeaders.value(i));
                    }
                    try{
                        String jsonData = response.body().string();
                        System.out.println("jsonData: " + jsonData);
                    } catch (Exception e){
                        e.getMessage();
                    }

                }
            }


            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call request, IOException e) {
                Log.d("EDMTERROR", "onfailure");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When sending a request the following code

```
String jsonData = response.body().string();
System.out.println("jsonData: " + jsonData);
```

gives

```
I/System.out: jsonData: {"get":"fixtures","parameters":{"league":"39","season":"2021","date":"2021-09-13"},"errors":{"token":"Error\/Missing application key. Go to https:\/\/www.api-football.com\/documentation-v3 to learn how to get your API application key."},"results":0,"paging":{"current":1,"total":1},"response":[]}
```

API-Sports has a dashboard with a live demo where you can basically send requests without code, **here it works, with the same api-key.**
I also tried renewing the api-key.

And like I said, it used to work.

I have tried contacting API-Sports via their chat function, but haven't received an answer in over a week.

Via the dashboard I can also see that their servers are up and running without issue.

Is there anything wrong in the code, is there anything else I could try? Or is this something on the API-side? In which case I have to try other ways to contact them?

Comment: Code seems fine. Since we aren't the server admins, not really much help we can provide. It's possible they limit the total amount of requests that you can make in some time period

Comment: @OneCricketeer Yeah, there is a limit, but I haven't gone over that limit. I think I'll just have to try to contact them again.

Comment: Try with curl and post the results.  That should be a better test than their own web based tools.